# Java thread to write to file

Tags: java, multithreading, file

I am trying to get a bit of experience in Java threads and synchronization with shared objects and perform simple lock.
What I am trying to do is to create Java application which inserts timestamps (or minutes) into text file with 2 different threads: one thread will insert only odd timestamps (or minutes) to file, the other thread will insert only even timestamps to same file. While one thread is inserting, the other thread cannot insert and waits until notified. The file contents must be after process is close (Ctrl+C in console) like this:

```
2013-05-10 21:37:02  
2013-05-10 21:37:03   
2013-05-10 21:37:04   
2013-05-10 21:37:05
```

or

```
2013-05-10 21:37    
2013-05-10 21:38   
2013-05-10 21:39   
2013-05-10 21:40
```

First of all I wanted just create one thread which will insert lines in file, and just cannot figure out what is wrong. Here is my code:

```
import java.io.*;

public class MyFileWriter
{
 private FileWriter fwriter;
 private BufferedWriter bufwriter;

 public FileWriter getWriter()
 {
    return this.fwriter;
  }

  public void setWriter(FileWriter pfwriter)
  {
     this.fwriter = pfwriter;
  }

  public BufferedWriter getBufWriter()
  {
    return this.bufwriter;
  }

  public void setBufWriter(BufferedWriter pbfwriter)
  {
    this.bufwriter = pbfwriter;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    MyFileWriter myfile = new MyFileWriter();

try
{ 
 FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("output.txt");
 myfile.setWriter(fstream);
 BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
 myfile.setBufWriter(out);
}
catch (IOException e)
{
 System.out.println("Error : "+e.getMessage());
}

MyThread mt = new MyThread();
mt.setBufWriter(myfile.getBufWriter());
mt.start();

    }
  }

class MyThread extends Thread
{ 
  private BufferedWriter bout;

  private int count = 1;

   public BufferedWriter getBufWriter()
  {
    return this.bout;
  }

   public void setBufWriter(BufferedWriter pbout)
   {
     this.bout = pbout;
   }

   public void run()
   {
    try
   {
     this.sleep(1000);
   }
   catch(InterruptedException e)
   {
     System.out.println("Error : "+e.getMessage());
   }

   try
   {
    this.bout.write("String # "+count);
    this.bout.newLine();
   }
   catch(IOException e)
   {
    System.out.println("Error : "+e.getMessage());
   }

   this.count++;
  }

}
```

I expect after MyThread mt is created and started, the thread will insert to file "output.txt" strings and after I execute Ctrl+C in Command Prompt, I will have something like this:

```
String #1
String #2
String #3
```

but the application finishes for some reason itself and I get empty file only (sometimes file has "String #1" when I launch app but mostly - empty). 
Can anyone enlighten me what am I doing wrong?

OS: Windows XP SP3, Java version:

java version "1.7.0_21"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_21-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 23.21-b01, mixed mode, sharing)

Answer (score 2):

Well, a couple things. First of all, your run() method only prints one line, and you only create one thread, so I'm not sure where you think the other lines will come from. `run()` will run once through in the new thread, and that's it. I guess you're assuming `run()` will be called in a loop, but it won't.

Secondly, you're using `BufferedWriter`, and this class buffers (holds on to) the data written to the stream before sending it to the file, so that a large amount of data can be written at once, for efficiency. The problem is that if you don't close or flush the `BufferedWriter` manually -- and you don't -- then your output will never be written to the file. If you add a call to `flush()` after each write to the `BufferedWriter`, you'll see all your output ends up in the file -- although that really removes the reason for using BufferedWriter in the first place!

A better solution would be to wait for the writing thread to terminate (using `Thread.join()` and then close the file in `main()`.

Comment: Thank you Ernest, sorted writing to file problem.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are doing anything regarding output to files or IO in java, you must always close the output device; in this case, it seems as if you are using the BufferedWriter as your output, so wherever you are writing to the file, at the end of that, just type

```
 <output>.close();
 <output> being the variable you use.
```

And that should write all your inforamtion to the file. HOpe this helps!!

Comment: Rather flush than close, if it is intended to write to the same file soon again.  But on the other hand, keeping a file open for very long times will prevent f.ex. external log rotation programs from working properly.

Answer (score 0):

To solve your immediate problem (concerning the single threaded example), **immediately after** `mt.start();` add this statement `mt.join();`.